# Unable to resolve java.awt.Desktop in AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp

Tags: authorization, youtube-data-api

I am trying to login to YouTube in my Android app by following https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#authorize_a_request
But I am encountering the below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Desktop;


at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:129)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113)                                                                             at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:81)
```

Below is the code:

```
    public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
            // Load client secrets.
            InputStream in = MainActivity.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client_secret.json"); //new FileInputStream("client_secret.json");
            clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader( in ));
            File file = new File(storePath);
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(file);
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();

            DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = DATA_STORE_FACTORY.getDataStore("blank");

            // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
            LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

            // Authorize.
            return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
    }
```

Can somebody help me with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android doesnt support this class. You need to somehow catch the authorisation and open that url in your browser manually